# Adding mapview into tabs in android

Tags: android, xml, dictionary, tabs, android-mapview

I have searched for tutorials and such on the internet, but i haven't come up with any solution that worked yet, so i though, why not ask it here??? I have managed to use mapviews outside the tabs, but how do i show the xml inside the map tab? Please anser and thanks in advance!
I need to add a MapView onto the "map" tab, how do i do this??? This is the XML code that i am using for the tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
/>
 <FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
 >
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
 >
 <TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="100px" 
android:text="My tracks"
android:id="@+id/txt1"
/>

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout

 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tab2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
 >
 <TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="100px" 
android:text="Map"
android:id="@+id/txt2"
/>

 </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tab3"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
 >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txt3"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Search for gokart tracks" />


 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/SearchInput"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="10.05" >

         <requestFocus />
     </EditText>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="@android:string/search_go" />

 </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding it in? There are instructions here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: Yeah, tried it. But no success...

Answer (score 3):

I have a project that has a `MapView` in `Tab`.

[image]

Here is the source and layout for the Tabs:
[Tab Source](https://github.com/willtate/Tour-Philly/blob/5bdc82d480c7fc4c31741c6db4a192cb33982efe/src/com/squidgle/philly/TabRoot.java)  |  [Tab XML](https://github.com/willtate/Tour-Philly/blob/5bdc82d480c7fc4c31741c6db4a192cb33982efe/res/layout/main.xml)

And here is the source and layout for the MapView that loads in the Tab:
[Map Source](https://github.com/willtate/Tour-Philly/blob/5bdc82d480c7fc4c31741c6db4a192cb33982efe/src/com/squidgle/philly/LocationMapActivity.java)  |  [Map XML](https://github.com/willtate/Tour-Philly/blob/5bdc82d480c7fc4c31741c6db4a192cb33982efe/res/layout/location_view.xml)

I hope you can adapt this code for your own project, good luck!

Comment: Tried it, but the problem is: that it just shows another window, it doesn't show the map inside the map tab. That's the problem. Btw, thanks very much

Comment: The code is working fine, I added a picture of what it looks like when running.

Comment: The code is way too far to go through the hole code, but could you post me the code that displays an xml layout file inside a tab?